# Change Tx Bluetooth Linux No Effect

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I would like to change the signal strength of my bluetooth device using linux command line (ubuntu 14.04).

I have found that I need to use the command

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 inqtpl
```

to change the signal strength but it's not working

---

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 inqtpl
```

gives me

[image]

---

and with hcidump

[image]

---

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 inqtpl 2
```

gives me

[image]

---

Using the command again

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 inqtpl
```

Gives me exactly the same thing than the first time. Nothing changed.

---

The command

```
sudo bccmd psget 0x0017
```

gives me

```
Unsupported manufacturer
```

---

Comment: It's very possible that particular hardware doesn't allow manually setting the power level...  but that's just a guess.

Comment: Yeah I am guessing this too :/ I hope there is some command to check it. Its for my job. I need to be sure that the industrial bluetooth card is wrong before asking to change it.

Ty for helping

Comment: Okay, I just tried what you did with my knock-off CSR dongle and got the same result.  I've never had to change the transmit power, so I'm not really sure if the way you're doing it is correct or not.  Hopefully someone else with another device can confirm or deny whether this is the right way to do this.  Maybe you need to have an established connection before making changes to the transmit level?  ... no idea.

Comment: I check that my bluetooth card is an Atheros AR3012. Maybe helpful.

Ty for checking, I hope that someone will confirm it

Comment: @RaNdoM_PoWneD Have you tried sudo bccmd psget -s 0x0000 0x0017

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After reading the Bluetooth specification, it says that only class 1 devices can change the transmitting power level by software. So first check the class of your device. I have read that Atheros AR3012 is class 1, so there shouldn't be a problem changing the tx power level. Maybe the device is capped or something is not working properly. I would ask the manufacturer.